# Vue.js page flipping effect not working as expected

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js

I'm developing a Vue.js application and am currently facing an issue with a page flip effect. The effect is implemented in a BookPage.vue component that's used within a parent Book.vue component. The issue is that the second side (side-2) of the page doesn't appear when I flip a page in the Book.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<template>
  <div
    class="page no-anim"
    :class="{ flipped: page.flipped }"
    @click="flipPage"
  >
    <div class="side-1">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>{{ page.content['side-1'].title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ page.content['side-1'].text }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="side-2">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>{{ page.content['side-2'].title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ page.content['side-2'].text }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps, defineEmits } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  page: Object,
})

const emit = defineEmits(['toggle-flip'])

const flipPage = () => {
  emit('toggle-flip', props.page.id)
}
</script>
<style>
.page {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transition: 0.8s;
}
[class*='side'] {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    0deg,
    transparent,
    transparent 25px,
    hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 0.15) 25px,
    hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 0.15) 26px
  );
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5% 8%;
}
.side-1 {
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: inset 50px 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.side-2 {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-shadow: inset -50px 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.flipped > .side-1 {
  box-shadow: inset 300px 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: 0.6s;
}
.flipped > [class*='side'] {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.page:after {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #555;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #222;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  content: 'next-page';
}
.page.flipped:after {
  content: 'prev-page';
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.no-anim,
.no-anim:after {
  animation: none; /* disable animation when page loads */
}
</style>
```

```
<template>
  <div class="book">
    <BookPage
      v-for="page in pages"
      :key="page.id"
      :page="page"
      @toggle-flip="toggleFlip"
      :style="{ zIndex: page.zIndex }"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import BookPage from './BookPage.vue'

const pages = ref([
  {
    id: 1,
    flipped: false,
    zIndex: 3,
    content: {
      'side-1': {
        title: 'Page 1 Front',
        text: 'Text for the front side of page 1.',
      },
      'side-2': {
        title: 'Page 1 Back',
        text: 'Text for the back side of page 1.',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    flipped: false,
    zIndex: 2,
    content: {
      'side-1': {
        title: 'Page 2 Front',
        text: 'Text for the front side of page 2.',
      },
      'side-2': {
        title: 'Page 2 Back',
        text: 'Text for the back side of page 2.',
      },
    },
  },
])

const toggleFlip = (pageId) => {
  console.log('Toggling flip for page:', pageId)
  const page = pages.value.find((p) => p.id === pageId)
  if (page) {
    page.flipped = !page.flipped
    computeZIndex()
  }
}

const computeZIndex = () => {
  let zIndexMax = pages.value.length
  pages.value.forEach((page, index) => {
    page.zIndex = page.flipped ? zIndexMax + index : zIndexMax - index
    console.log('New z-index for page', page.id, ':', page.zIndex)
  })
}

onMounted(() => {
  computeZIndex()
})
</script>
<style>
.book {
  height: 80%;
  max-height: 500px;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 800px;
  background: #964b00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid hsla(30, 10%, 20%, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 150px hsla(170, 0%, 0%, 0.4);
}
</style>
```

When a page in BookPage.vue is clicked, the toggle-flip event is emitted and handled in Book.vue, which toggles the flipped state for that page. However, despite this, when I flip a page, side-2 doesn't appear as expected.
The .flipped class is being applied correctly, and I've tried adjusting the transform and backface-visibility properties in my CSS, but to no avail.
Any guidance on what's causing this and how to solve it would be greatly appreciated.